# How to import part of object in ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, module, browserify, ecmascript-6, commonjs

In the [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) I found this way to import PureRenderMixin

```
var PureRenderMixin = require('react/addons').addons.PureRenderMixin;
```

How can it be rewritten in ES6 style. The only thing I can do is:

```
import addons from "react/addons";
let PureRenderMixin = addons.addons.PureRenderMixin;
```

I hope there is a better way.

Comment: Maybe `import {addons:{PureRenderMixin}} from 'react/addons'`

Comment: @elclanrs no ( at least it is not working with babel )

Comment: This is very similar to [Passing options to ES6 module imports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29923879/1048572) - not yet possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ES6 - Convert from 'require' to 'import'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30898686/1048572)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unfortunately [import statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) does not work like [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Curly braces here mean that you want to import token with this name but not property of default export. Look at this pairs of import/export:

```
 //module.js
 export default 'A';
 export var B = 'B';

 //script.js
 import A from './a.js';  //import value on default export
 import {B} from './a.js'; // import value by its name
 console.log(A, B); // 'A', 'B'
```

For your case you can import whole object and make a destructuring assignment

```
 import addons from "react/addons";
 let {addons: {PureRenderMixin}} = addons;
```

Comment: `import {addons} from 'react/addons'; 
const {PureRenderMixin} = addons;` works too.
Also take a look at https://github.com/gaearon/react-pure-render#mixin

Answer (score 4):

```
import PureRenderMixin from 'react-addons-pure-render-mixin';
```

See example [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html).