# is there any way to obtain a reference to (and use) an es6/2015 import in the same expression?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, es6-module-loader

in node (common-js), i can do something similar to the following:

```
resultA = require('objectA').key1;
//
resultB = require('functionB')(42);
//
resultC = require('functionC')();
```

with es6/2015 modules, i'm currently using something similar to this:

```
import objectA from 'objectA'; 
resultA = objectA.key1;
//
import functionB from 'functionB'; 
resultB = functionB(42);
//
import functionC from 'functionC'; 
resultC = functionC();
```

is there a short-hand syntax available, or is this the most concise way of accomplishing the desired behavior?

Comment: Actually, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: You'd have to elaborate then, because that seems like the same question to me. Or are you referring to the fact that those answers use a module loader instead of import syntax? The answer is still the same, there is no way, an import statement just defines variable names like `var someImport;`

Comment: @torazaburo: Yeah, the question is a bit off with "*is there a more concise way?*" instead of "*what's the best way?*", but the answers in the dupe already do show the most concise way; the answer to this question would be a simple **No** (which is too short to post it as an answer)

Comment: See also [How to import part of object in ES6 modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121801/how-to-import-part-of-object-in-es6-modules)