# ES6 - Convert from 'require' to 'import'

Tags: ecmascript-6

**If the alternative to:**

```
var Foo = require('foo');
```

**is:**

```
import Foo from 'foo';
```

**What is the alternative to:**

```
var Bar = require('foo').batz
```

**Could it be:**

```
import {batz}  from 'foo' ?
```

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with ReactJS. Could you change your tag from reactjs to ecmascript-6?

Comment: And what about `require('foo');` without storing it in a var? `import` seems to need a variable, can I just use anything random?

Comment: @Kokodoko a little late, but `import './file';` would be the equivalent!

Comment: Can someone explain with PERMUTATIONS of all filenames what is going on with the first version? I do not think it works in general. The NAMES are critical surely?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Nearly. It does however depend on how you are exporting them.

- named exports (`export var batz = …`):

  ```
  import {batz as Bar} from 'foo';
  ```
- default-exported object (`export default {batz: …};`) - should not be used:

  ```
  import Foo from 'foo';
  var Bar = Foo.batz;
  ```

Comment: "default-exported object [...] should not be used" – could you explain why not?

Comment: @Pavlo: Because, as you can see, the import sytax is awkward :-) At least in this case named exports are much more appropriate (I'm not *generally* advising against default exports).

Comment: ```import { foo: { batz } } from 'foo';

console.log(batz);```

Comment: @szines: Nope, you can only [bind to `BindingIdentifier`s](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports), you cannot use destructuring here.

Comment: @Bergi Ah thanks. However in Ember.js you can do that what I wrote, probably it is a frameworks specific thing.

Comment: @szines: Or a transpiler extension. Maybe there's an ES7 proposal for it that I don't know of.

Comment: what about `var Bar = require('foo').batz()` ?

Comment: @DragonKnight see the related [Pass options to ES6 module imports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29923879/1048572). You need to split that into the import declaration and the statement that actually calls the initialisation function. Typically `import { batz } from 'foo'; const Bar = batz();`