# How would I rewrite this statement in TypeScript ES6 style 'EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter'?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

Like the title states, I would like to rewrite the statement below in TypeScript

```
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
```

to ES6 style

```
import {EventEmitter} from "events"
```

I'm not sure whether these two are equivalent, in fact I *think* they aren't because when I'm trying to use RxJS with the second statement above it doesn't compile the example below whereas it does with the first one.

I'm getting the following error when I'm using the second statement above.

```
.build/lib/process.ts(12,3): error TS2345: Argument of type 'EventEmitter' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ on: (name: string, cb: (e: any) => any) => void; off: (name: string, cb: (e: any) => any) => vo...'.
    Property 'off' is missing in type 'EventEmitter'.
```

Example:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    Rx = require('rx');

var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(
  eventEmitter,
  'data',
  function (foo, bar) { return { foo: bar, bar: bar }; });

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: foo -' + x.foo + ', bar -' + x.bar);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });

eventEmitter.emit('data', 'baz', 'quux');
// => Next: foo - baz, bar - quux
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ES6 - Convert from 'require' to 'import'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30898686/1048572) - not sure because of the Typescript involvement though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like the *solution* but what I did to make it work is switch off the types using 'any'.

```
var eventEmitter: any = new EventEmitter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind it works! it's just an issue with Rx definition files.

I changed the following.

```
import * as Rx from "rx"
```

to

```
const Rx = require('rx')
```

and kept the ES6 import style to import the EventEmitter.

Comment: by using `const Rx = require('rx')` you are *switching off type checking for the `Rx` variable*.  Don't do this.

Comment: Yup, I know but it seems like I have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

> Argument of type 'EventEmitter' is not assignable

Reading the docs : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md your example *should definitely work*.

This is a bug in the definitions for RX. The type definitions should explicitly support `EventEmitter` or make it compatible with EventEmitter instances.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by using the Rx event emitter? what do I need to do in order for it to work?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. Fixed answer after reading the docs and investigating further