# Import statement using .get in the statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Changing some files from the old way to the newer way (ES6) for import statements. I have a statement like this that has a 'get' in it so it gets the whole JSON file that is at somefolder/somefolder/filename.

```
let variable = require('somefolder/somefolder').get('filename');
```

I want to change it to something like this:

```
import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

or

```
import React from 'react';
```

Clarification that makes it a non-duplicate question. I want to use the import statement and the ".get" in one line of code (without functions like the previous solution) at the top of the file.

Comment: @bergi - this is not a duplicate question. The question you reference does not have the .get on the end which does affect the syntax of the import statement. It doesn't compile. Please unmark it. Thanks

Comment: Whether you are invoking a method on the required module (`….get(something)`) or trying to call the required module itself (`…(something)`) doesn't really make a difference here, the takeaway is that you need to split it in two separate statements when using `import` syntax. There is no oneliner solution.

Comment: That is what I needed - splitting it into two. Which I don't want to do. If that is the only way, then I will leave it like it is ES5 and below.

Comment: *"If that is the only way"* It is.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [ES6 - Convert from 'require' to 'import'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30898686/1048572) (which has `.get` but no call). There's really nothing wrong with splitting it into two lines. Embrace ES6 :-)

Comment: Thanks all. Been a big help.

Comment: Think about `import` statements as "directives" that tell the interpreter which dependencies to load, not as code that is actually executed.