# Equivalent of requiring a subproperty in ES6 import

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, require

I have an existing `require`:

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
```

I started using Babel for ES6, and would like to `import` this instead. So far I have:

```
import electron from 'electron';
const {dialog} = electron.remote;
```

This is ugly, and I can't help but feel there is a better way to do this. I **just** need the dialog here. How do I get at it in one line?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way using ES6 imports to also do a deep destructure, so what you're doing is about as good as can be done at the moment.

Comment: Related: [ES6 - Convert from 'require' to 'import'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30898686/218196)

Answer (score 3):

ECMAScript module syntax doesn't allow deep destructuring. In fact it doesn't destructure at all. Import statements create live bindings between modules.

Here is great blog post written by Ben Nadel. It should shed some light on bindings: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3131-the-import-statement-creates-a-live-view-of-modules-in-es6-and-typescript-in-angular-2.htm

So by doing

```
import electron from 'electron';
const {dialog} = electron.remote;
```

`electron` is such binding. By doing destructuring assignment `dialog` is normal constant and it won't be "bound" to electron module (it won't update).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing 'ugly', it is how the things should be written in ES6.

`import`s are supposed to be statically analyzed without script evaluation, supported syntax is limited. Default import can't be destructured in `import` statement, all varieties of syntax [are listed in the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

It can be written as

```
import electron from 'electron';
const { remote: { dialog } } = electron;
```