# Is it possible to use ES6 import without creating a variable and execute in a single line, similar to CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules, commonjs

Just wondering, am I able to import ES6 modules without creating a "placeholder" variable and run it immediately?

for instance, instead of ES6's import that creates an unused `express` variable:

```
import express from 'express' 
const app = express();
```

In CommonJS I can do it without it:

```
const app = require("express")();
```

This is particularly useful for one time only imports such as `dotenv`:

```
require("dotenv").config();
```

Instead of

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config();
//or
import {} from 'dotenv/config'
config()
```

Which I think CommonJS syntax is much cleaner, but it seems ES6 imports are the future.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 - Convert from 'require' to 'import'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30898686/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way for that in ES6, but there's [a finshed (Stage 4) proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) for doing this:

```js
(await import('dotenv')).config()
```

Or, if the target module doesn't provide named export:

```js
(await import('dotenv')).default.config()
```

However, you should note that `await` can only be used inside an async function (until [this another proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) gets implemented):

```js
(async ()=>{
  (await import('dotenv'))/*.default*/.config()
})()
```

Comment: [Top-level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) is at Stage 3, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way other than mentioning the placeholders(default export or export names) to import ES6 module.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import