# ES6 module import group of files with individual exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I would like to combine some modules into a single file that can be imported. These are local files and not part of an npm module.

Module Kitten (kitten.js)

```
export function Feed() {}
export function Play() {}
```

In my code I can access  'Feed' and 'Play':

```
// This works but I would like to avoid this due to my paths
import { Feed, Play } from './some/long/path/kitten.js'

// Then use it
Feed()
```

As I have many 'pets' I can contenate them in a master file - say pets.js

```
export * as Kitten from './some/long/path/kitten.js'
export * as Puppies from './some/long/path/puppies.js'
...
```

In my code I can then do:

```
import { Kitten, Puppies } from './pets'

// Then use it as
Kitten.Feed()
```

is it possible to have both a) the master pets file and b) call `Feed()` without doing `Kitten.Feed()`?

The following doesn't work as it's not a valid path. It's possible it would work as 'pets/Kitten' if it was an npm module -  am not sure.

```
import { Feed, Play } from './pets/Kitten'
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
import * as Pets from from './pets'
import { Feed, Play } from Pets.Kitten // or 'Pets/Kitten'
```

But clearly that doesn't work. I am wondering if it's at all possible.

I am using this in Node with Babel 6 and ES6 module loading. I see a lot of similar questions but they all use default exports which I am not using.

Comment: Python community will give u answer.. wait 3 min at most

Comment: Instead of `export default { Puppy, Kitten }` couldn't you just do `export Puppy; export Kitten`?

Comment: @gcampbell - trying variations but no go

Comment: FYI, the module loader is not part of ES6. If you run the code in Node for example, then you are using Node's module loader. You can read about it how it works: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: @FelixKling I am aware of this. I am using the ES6 module loader as handled by Babel 6 and my question should be tagged accordingly

Comment: Babel6 only transpiles your code, it doesn't do any module loading. All it does is converting `import Foo from 'bar';` into `var Foo = require('bar');`.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but it sounds like a duplicate of [import modules from files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29722270/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi - not the same - they have default exports. I think I will close this question and look at the RxJS code to see how they did it.

Comment: @Yashua: It's [possible with default exports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34072598/1048572) just as well

Answer (score 1):

> But that doesn't allow me to import selected functions.

Sure it does. The relative-path import works the same as module import. You can destructure the results just the same.

```
import { Play } from 'Pet/Puppy';
// is identical to
import { Play } from '../node_modules/Pet/Puppy';
```

If you take a look at [the `import` syntax (s15.2.2)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports), you can see that the `from` part expects a string. It doesn't care what's in the string, that's up to the module system (the browser, node, etc).

Comment: In the first case you must have it as an npm module correct?  The second won't work for me really as the point of concatenating is that my subfiles have complex path so i am looking for a one entry file.

Comment: The first syntax is for including a file from a module, yeah. When you concatenate, the result won't have any paths, it will replace the `import` (or `require`) with a reference to the module from the same file.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand correctly the answer to my question is "no way - unless you publish it as a module"?

Comment: Not at all. You can absolutely import and re-export symbols from a local file. Once you concatenate the files in your module, you're simply exporting the symbol like normal (without needing to import it).

Comment: I'm sorry for being obtuse but how? We agree that example #1 is not possible without publishing and #2 won't work (or is not manageable) due to the complex path. You have `'../node_modules/Pet/Puppy` which assumes a file called Puppy. I tried in hopes that it would guess I wanted the exported 'Puppy' module but it just throws errors about files not found

Comment: The second option *will* work, that's how we bundle exports in libraries. I'm using something almost identical [here](https://github.com/ssube/noicejs/blob/master/src/main/inject.js#L8) and it works just fine. Your concatenation tool need to replace the path with a reference, that's all. That's how browserify and webpack and every other tool I'm aware of handles it (more or less).

Comment: I just tried your code with same errors: https://gist.github.com/429542e01c45c46d79739e3a38b94d95 - Cannot find module './inject/Injector'

Comment: What does your build process look like? If it's an extensive explanation, we can [take it over to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17).

Comment: No build process. NodeJS Babel transpiling on the fly with babel-node

Comment: That's definitely part of your problem. You need to use a concatenation tool that's aware of modules or make sure the relative paths remain valid.

Answer (score 1):

Ah.. object destructuring.. Forgot about that.

```
import { Kitten, Puppies } from './pets'
const {Feed, Play} = Kitten;
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30132149/856498