# Importing an Object with SubObjects and Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

I have a theme object that has a number of objects and arrays as values.  I.e., something like this:

```
export const theme = {
  colors: {...list of colors},
  breakpoints: [...array of breakpoints],
  ...
}
```

Now, let's say I want to access the color object and breakpoints array in another document.  Currently, I am importing theme like this:

```
import { theme } from '../../theme'
const { colors, breakpoints: bp } = theme
}
```

I am using `breakpoints: bp` so that I can alias `breakpoints` as `bp` in my file.

What I am wondering is whether or not it is possible to do all this in the import statement. I.e., instead of importing the entire `theme` object, to import just the color object and breakpoint array.  Something like this (this code does NOT works, it's just to illustrate the idea):

```
import { theme.colors as colors, theme.breakpoints as bp } from '../../theme'
```

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that unfortunately, the [import statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) do not support the [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

I found this thread where this question was explained

[How to import part of object in ES6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121801/how-to-import-part-of-object-in-es6-modules)

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you should change the way you export the theme. You could just export each property of theme - it's as simple as removing the const declaration and just exporting the object. :

```
export {
  colors: {...list of colors},
  breakpoints: [...array of breakpoints],
  ...
}
```

and then using import as such:

```
import { colors, breakpoints as bp } from '../../themes'
```