# ES6 equivalent of Node.js require function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

What's the shortest ES6 equivalent of `require` function call below?

```
module.exports = function(app) {...};

require('./routes')(app);
```

In other words is there a one-liner equivalent in ES6 modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just started to delve into ES6, but I believe that would be something like:

```
import * as routes from './routes';
```

...assuming `./routes` is an ES6 module exporting something.

This can then be used immediately like so:

```
import * as routes from './routes';

doAThing( routes.myVar, routes.myMethod() );
```

If the module has only a single named export, it's still two lines to import, then call:

```
import { name } from './routes';
name();
```

This is the same for any number of exports:

```
import { name1, name2 } from './routes';
name1();
name2();
```

A better import is as written above:

```
import * as routes from './routes';
routes.foo();
routes.bar();
```

I used the "recommended" format from [this Axel Rauschmayer post](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html) relating to ES6 modules, but depending on what the module exports your import statement may look different:

> import * as fs from 'fs'; // recommended

I find this (1 line to import, 1 line to invoke) syntax clear and readable, so I like it. For some, it may seem unfortunate. However, the bottom line is that [**there is no one line import/invoke in ES6**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29924193/597122)

Comment: That's just import.  I'm interested in calling the imported function inline.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Let me double check the syntax and see if I can update any further.

Comment: Yes, so we get 2 lines in ES6 modules vs 1 line `require('...')()` in Node.js.  Is there a one-liner?

Comment: @kyrylkov the `import` statement syntax does not provide any way to use an imported value as part of an expression. All it does is bind the value to a symbol.

Comment: @kyrylkov no one-liner. Also I'm not sure if `imports` have to be at the top of files, whereas nodes commonJS you can `require` anywhere in a file. Certainly with babel transpilation you must import early, but I'm not sure if thats a constraint of transpilation or following spec.