# Load and use an ES6 module in one expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, module

With node.js module syntax you can load a module and use it all in one expression:

```
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
```

Is there any equivalent for ES6 modules?

```
import os from 'os';
const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;
```

is the closest I can get; this is two full statements, and leaves me with an unwanted binding for `os`.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Pass options to ES6 module imports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29923879/218196)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Bindings to modules happen statically when the file's being parsed, and before it's executed. The only way to achieve what you're trying to do is to use a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports).

```
export const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;
```

Which will allow you to specify the named export in your program's entry point:

```
import { numCPUs } from 'os';
```

Comment: We have to keep `export const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;` in another file then import from it, right?

Comment: Yes. If you need to defer the execution until after the program's finished initialising, you can have it return a promise, or export the function that supplies the value instead.