# Rewriting something like require('shipit-deploy')(shipit) in ES6 import?

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, require

I'm trying to find an example for es6 form of the following:

`require('shipit-deploy')(shipit)`

I would usually go for something like

`import 'shipit-deploy'`

however in this case there is `(shipit)` at the end of require that I am not entirely sure how to import correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass options to ES6 module imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923879/pass-options-to-es6-module-imports)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require('shipit-deploy')(shipit)` works by first requiring the specified module, and then calling the result with `shipit` as argument. You can achieve the same result by first importing `'shipit-deploy'` into some variable, and then calling the result with `shipit` as argument.

```
import shipitDeployImport from 'shipit-deploy'
const shipitDeploy = shipitDeployImport(shipit)
```