# How do you import a function with parameters using ECMAScrip6?

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am setting up a brand new project in *Express* using *Babel* and *ESLint*, and am trying to setup dynamic routes. The only issue is that I cannot figure out how to call the loader for the routes. This is my current code regarding the loader.
**routes/index.js**

```
import fs from 'fs';

/**
 * Register Default Routes
 * @param {Object} app express.Application
 */
export default function(app) {
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach((fileName) => {
        if (fileName == __filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1)) return;
        let fileNameStripped = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
        require('./' + fileNameStripped)(app); // does not work
    });
}
```

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes/index.js';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

routes(app); // works now

...
```

**Babel Error**

```
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at /app/build/routes/index.js:1:314
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at exports.default (/app/build/routes/index.js:1:195)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/index.js:1:393)    
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
```

The issue appears to be related to https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2683

Comment: This was based off of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923879/pass-options-to-es6-module-imports, although it did not work.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Does the code above not work for you, and if it doesn't, what's wrong with it? I don't see why it's important that it's an import. It's a function that can accept an argument, imported or not.

Comment: This issue is that the function is not called, the one in routes/index.js and index.js

Comment: Well, it should, because you call it. If there are problems, there should be errors. Currently nobody but you can debug it. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem - a repo, online service or else. Otherwise the question is considered off-topic.

Comment: Alright, editing..

Comment: You haven't posted nested route files. But I guess they use ES module `default` exports too, so `require('./' + fileNameStripped)` is module object, and it should be `require('./' + fileNameStripped).default(app)`.

Comment: Thanks @estus, can you create a answer with the content from the comment above this as it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nested route files are supposed to be ES modules with `default` exports, `require('./' + fileNameStripped)` is module object and not a function. It should be:

```
require('./' + fileNameStripped).default(app);
```

Depending on Babel configuration ([`dynamic-import-node`](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node) plugin is required), `require()` can be replaced with dynamic `import()` but it's less desirable here, because dynamic `import` is not synchronous and can cause race conditions.