# import dynamic components in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

fairly new to react.js, but prototyping a concept and getting stuck.

I want to have a component that delivers a variable name back (that it gets from an API), then based on that name, import a bunch of files that would share the same name in a folder structure, i.e.;

Folder structure

```
src/components/test/comp1.js
src/components/test/comp2.js
```

Then in my App component

```
import GetName from './components/apiRequest.GetName';
import Comp1 from './components/<GetName />/comp1';
```

Were GetName would deliver 'test' - But i can't do this, i just get a 'failed to compile' - any ideas on where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Do you want to pass a value through import?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do!

Comment: Even if it is possible, I don't think it's a good way to do, if you don't mind I can try to show you other ways.

Comment: Sure thing, suggest away. I basically want to load a set of HTML elements depending on the specific variable name I'm delivered back from our api. These would be physical HTML pages/ react components in separate folder structure, named the same as the variable I get back from api

Comment: take a look at this answer, i think you can make it work with a factory like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923879/pass-options-to-es6-module-imports?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Normally we pass values through props, but the solution above should work

Comment: If you want to do this to save some bandwidth, you can use webpack's [dynamic import](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)

Answer (score 1):

The way you suggested won't work because GetName will return a React Component not a plain string that you can interpolate.

Assuming that you have a function GetName that returns a plain string rather than a component you can use the require api for a dynamic import.

```
//external module
function GetName(){
 //here you put your logic to return the name
 return "MyComponent";

}
```

and

```
class App extends Component {
  //App component
  render(){
    const myComp = require(`./components/${GetName()}`).default;
  }

}
```