# Pass options to ES6 module imports not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

Following this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923879/pass-options-to-es6-module-imports) question, I am trying to pass options to ES6 imports?

This worked fine:

```
export default (Param1:any, Param2:any) => {
    return class Foo {
        constructor() {
            console.log(Param1);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I need to return more than one class so I tried this:

```
export default (Param1: any, Param2: any)=>{

       class Foo {
            constructor() {
                console.log(Param1);
            }
        }
       class Bar {
            constructor() {
                console.log(Param1);
            }
        }
        return {Foo, Bar}
}
```

But I got the following error on compilation:

> TS4060: Return type of exported function has or is using private name
>   Foo TS4060: Return type of exported function has or is using private
>   name Bar

How to pass options to ES6 imports that imports multiple class ?

Comment: This only happens when using the `--declarations` option in the compiler. In general, this methodology isn't recommended for TypeScript because of the way Microsoft maps their types. Instead, you'll need to do something similar to @Talha 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just export the classes separately:

```
export class Foo {
    constructor(Param1) {
        console.log(Param1);
    }
}

export class Bar {
    constructor(Param1) {
        console.log(Param1);
    }
}
```

Then you can import like so:

```
import {Foo, Bar} from './your/path/to/module.js
```