# How to import socket.io npm packege - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

```js
const socketio = new Server();
```

> import Server from 'socket.io';
> SyntaxError: The requested module 'socket.io' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: it should be `import * as io from 'sockt.io'`

Comment: ```const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const socketio = io(server);```
I am still getting the following error
```const socketio = io(server);
                 ^

TypeError: io is not a function```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass options to ES6 module imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923879/pass-options-to-es6-module-imports)

Comment: unfortunatly no

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two kinds of exports: named exports (several per module) and default exports (one per module). It is possible to use both at the same time, but usually it is best to keep them separate.

Why are you receiving this error: The import statement you wrote, provides the `Server` which is not a default export. If socket.io had actually exported Server as below, then you would not get an error.

```
module.exports = {
  //Other exports
  Server as default
}
```

<strike>You could have done this:</strike>

```
import * as io from "socket.io"
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';

const app = express(); 
const server = createServer(app); 
const socketio = new io.Server(server);
```

Edit:

You can import socket.io like this:

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';

const app = express(); 
const server = createServer(app); 
const socketio = new Server(server);
```

Comment: ```import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import * as io from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const socketio = io(server);```

Comment: here is the error ```const socketio = io(server);
                 ^

TypeError: io is not a function```

Comment: import it like then then: `import { io } from 'socket.io'`

Comment: ```import { io } from 'socket.io';
         ^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'socket.io' does not provide an export named 'io'```

Comment: When I try this method, I just get io.Server is not a constructor error.. =/  any ideas what might be causing that?

Answer (score 2):

I can not beleive Socket.io is making it so difficult to import their npm package.

Here is the answer. Thank you @MeghAgarwal

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';

const app = express(); 
const server = createServer(app); 
const socketio = new Server(server);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of v3, the correct way to do it is:

```js
const httpServer = require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(content));
  res.end(content);
});
// Or const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app) if you use express

const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);
```

And if you `import * as io from 'socket.io'`, you got to call `io.io(httpServer)`. I ran into the same error

Comment: this is what i did
```const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
// socketio
const socketio = io(server);```

Comment: const server = require('http').createServer(app) would do the trick @John

Comment: I need to use ```import```

Comment: I also used `import * as io from 'socket.io' `, but I had to do `const socket = new io.Server(server, . . . . .`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. This works for me

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const io = require("socket.io")(80);
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
```